# Not getting order details on onestep checkout page

Tags: orders, event-observer, payment

I am trying to get order details on onestep checkout but its not working. My xml code is like this :

```
<checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
                <observers>
                    <pmembers_invoicer_automatically_complete_order>
                        <class>MKD_Pmembers_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>CompleteOrder</method>
                    </pmembers_invoicer_automatically_complete_order>
                </observers>
            </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
```

My observer code is follow:

```
 $_order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
            $order =$observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
             $oid = $order -> getId();
```

It give `Fatal error:  Call to a member function getId() on a non-object`. Am I doing something wrong. I want to make some changes on payment made. I know some uses `sales_order_payment_pay` for payment verification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code in your observer to get the order:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
$incrementId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();
$order->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);
```

on success event.

Comment: would this code works on observer ? as i am working on event and observer.

Comment: yes updated the answer with the word 'observer' :)

Comment: Any issue if i use success event instead of payment ? i think that user can only go to success if he payed.thanks for your help

Comment: in your question you are using success event and my answer is also for the same.

Answer (score 1):

`checkout_onepage_controller_success_action`, which is thrown by **Mage_Checkout_OnepageController** class in its **successAction()** function when the customer is shown the checkout success page.

You can get the order id by the following

```
public function CompleteOrder(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {

    $orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();

    if (!is_array($orderIds) || (!array_key_exists(0, $orderIds))) {
        return;
    }

    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderIds[0]);

    if (!$order->getId()) {
        return;
    }

    // Do your stuff

}
```